# Paypal instead of in-app purchase/billing on Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, paypal, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm somewhat confused by the terms of the developer content policy ([here](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html)). Is it possible to use Paypal (or any alternative paying method) instead of in-app purchase (iOS) and in-app billing (Android) for a monthly-recurring PREMIUM membership on my app?

A premium member can access more content and doesn't see ads, but by reading the guidelines, it seems that I must use the built-in in-app purchasing program, is that correct or am I just a bad reader?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know about Android but the only way you can avoid in-app purchase for this scenario on iOS is if he user signs-up/pays on another website and the uses credentials in your app. The app cannot allow the user to register on the web site or link to the subscription/payment area

Comment: Wouldn't that make iOS/Android ban my app? As I would be using a sneaky way to get around using their billing system, thus them making profit on the benefits.

Comment: Only Apple/Google can say for sure but have a look at Eventboard on the Apple Store for one app that uses this approach

Comment: Ok thank you for the reference :) I really appreciate your help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont know about android but your app will be rejected. According to section 11.2 of the App Store Review Guidelines for iOS (Login Required) any app that doesn't use In-App purchase will be rejected.

```
11.2 Apps utilizing a system other than the In App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an app will be rejected
```

Additionally, note that any purchase of real world goods or services is not allowed as per section 11.3. I suggest reading the whole document, or at least section 11 (and 20 if it's a charity app). That should give you a pretty good idea of what's allowed and what's not.

Comment: But some of the most papula shopping sites are using external paymentgateways, other than in-app purchase.How that works?

Comment: Yes, a popular ecommerce platform offers a subscription-based model but doesn't have any in-app purchases, instead, they are receiving payments using the web view. Can anyone tell me how we can achieve this?